# Color change from light-mode to dark-mode not working in SwiftUI on real device

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios-darkmode, lightmode

Using Swift5.3.2, iOS14.4.1, Xcode12.4,

I try to make a custom-Color change when switching from light to dark mode in SwiftUI.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyTestView : View {
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color("loginBG"))
        }
    }
}
```

The `MyTestView` is called right at the beginning of my App lifecycle (real simple example):

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct myApp: App {
        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyTestView()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Color definition of `loginBG`:

[image]

Here is the video showing that the Rectangle does unfortunately not change color - why ?????

(from the status-Bar color-switch you can see that I indeed changed from light-mode to dark-mode and back. But no Rectangle-Color change at all)

[image]

Comment: It works. I'm using iOS 14.4 simulator & Xcode 12.4

Comment: yeah - in Simulator it works.... but not on a real device (iPhoneX) !!!!!  (...I tried with having the real device connected to the simulator and also standalone - but none works)

Comment: @iKK, did you ever manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyTestView : View {
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "loginBG")))
        }
    }
}
```

replace the `Color("loginBG")` to `Color(UIColor(named: "loginBG"))`

This can work for me with real device.